# Autofilter based off drop down

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, automation

I'm trying to create an auto filter that takes what is in A2 of "sheet1" and changes the filter on "Sheet2" in F2 and below;

This is the code so far, all I need is to make it look at the different sheets

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then
        If Range("F2") = "All" Then
            Range("A2").AutoFilter
        Else
            Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Range("F2")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify in which workbook/worksheet your ranges are. Otherwise VBA cannot know that.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2") = "All" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").AutoFilter
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Never use `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows` or `Columns` without specifying the workbook and the worksheet they are in. Otherwise Excel "guesses" and it might guess wrong.

Comment: Oh Brilliant, thank you so much, I tries ThisWorkBook.Sheet("Sheet1").Range... thank you, and if I wanted to do it off of a 2nd cell could i add an AND value in there before the first "End if" ? or would it come after or is that even allowed in VBA? - basically want to do the same but based off the cell B2 instead of A2 but have it depending on both of them

Comment: Nvm Figured it out, still thank you very muvh @Peh